# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql

I have small errors when I add date to my database.

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\chemmad\register.php on line 17.
```

But it works fine in my web server, but it is not working from local host.

Comment: Can we have your PHP code to see where is the error ?

Comment: Have you tried searching for this exact error message and following any of the ton of advise that's already available for it?!

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_num_rows` is deprecated and you should not use it.

The correct way to count the number of rows in php is:

```
$db = new PDO( ... db connection details ...);
$q = $db->query('SELECT a, b, c FROM tbl WHERE oele = 2 GROUP BY boele');
$rows = $q->num_rows;

print $rows;
```